Flutter Camera Plugin: Unable to Open Front-Facing Camera
I'm working on a Flutter project where I need to open the front-facing camera, but no matter what I try, the camera always starts facing the back. I'm unfamiliar with the project, and I'm having trouble figuring out how to get the front-facing camera to open by default.
I'm running that getCameras() function and when that completes it should update my cameras list. Then setting my current camera to the one with front facing camera. I also tried choosing a specific index from the list but it was only ever the back camera
class _CameraState extends State<Camera>
    with WidgetsBindingObserver, SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  final GlobalKey<ConvexAppBarState> appBarKey;
  _CameraState({this.appBarKey});
  //Global Scaffold Key
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  FlutterSecureStorage storage = FlutterSecureStorage();

  //Video and Camera variables
  CameraController cameraController;
  VideoPlayerController videoController;
  VoidCallback videoPlayerListener;
  XFile videoFile;
  String uploadVideoPath;
  bool enableAudio = true;
  double _minAvailableExposureOffset = 0.0;
  double _maxAvailableExposureOffset = 0.0;
  double _currentExposureOffset = 0.0;
  double _minAvailableZoom = 1.0;
  double _maxAvailableZoom = 1.0;
  double _currentScale = 1.0;
  double _baseScale = 1.0;
  int _pointers = 0;
  bool _recordFirstPress;
  bool showPath = true;
  Timer _countdownTimer;
  bool showCounter;
  int _start = 3;
  bool changeIcon;
  AnimationController _animationController;
  List<CameraDescription> cameras = [];
  bool _cameraOn = true;
  CameraDescription currentCamera;
  //Video Upload Variable
  final ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker();

  //Spoon Variables
  bool _spoonActive;
  double circles = 1.0;
  bool spoonButtonUpdate;
  bool showMessage;
  double spreadRadius;
  Color spreadColor;
  List<SpoonSet> spoonSets = [];
  SpoonSet currentSet = SpoonSet();
  String _templateValue = 'Standard Template';
  List<DropdownMenuItem> _templates = [];
  List<Widget> _spoonWidgets = [];
  List<dynamic> _spoonQuestions;
  List<Widget> dots = [];
  int currentSpoon = 1;

  //Initialize screen
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    showMessage = true;
    spoonButtonUpdate = false;
    checkSpoonAlert();
    spreadRadius = 0;
    spreadColor = Colors.transparent;
    showCounter = false;
    changeIcon = false;
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
    _animationController = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: Duration(seconds: 120),
    )..addStatusListener((status) {
        if (status == AnimationStatus.completed) {
          onStopButtonPressed();
          setState(() {
            _animationController.value = 0;
          });
        }
      });
    _animationController.value = 0.0;
    _recordFirstPress = true;
    _spoonActive = false;

    loadSpoon();

    Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 1000)).whenComplete(() {
      setState(() {
        spoonButtonUpdate = !spoonButtonUpdate;
        spreadRadius = 2.0;
        spreadColor = Colors.white.withOpacity(0.8);
      });
    });

    getCameras().whenComplete(() {
      currentCamera = cameras.firstWhere(
          (camera) => camera.lensDirection == CameraLensDirection.front);
      onNewCameraSelected(currentCamera);
    });
  }


What camera package are you using? I don't see getCameras in the official camera package API

If you're using the camera package, you need to initialize the camera controller with the CameraDescription that correlates to the front-facing camera. I don't see that initialization code in your question but here is a basic example:
import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CameraView extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<CameraView> createState() => _CameraViewState();
}

class _CameraViewState extends State<CameraView> {
  bool loading = true;
  late List<CameraDescription> _cameras;
  late CameraController? controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    availableCameras().then((cameras) {
      _cameras = cameras;

      CameraDescription frontFacingCamera = cameras.firstWhere((camera) => camera.lensDirection == CameraLensDirection.front);

      controller = CameraController(frontFacingCamera, ResolutionPreset.medium);
      controller!.initialize().then((_) {
        if (!mounted) {
          return;
        }
        setState(() {
          loading = false;
        });
      });
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (loading) {
      return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
    }
    if (controller != null && !controller!.value.isInitialized) {
      return Container();
    }
    return Scaffold(body: CameraPreview(controller!));
  }
}

